# How to resolve the 'params.json file does not exist' error when installing/configuring Bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla

While installing/configuring Bugzilla ; I am facing this issue. Please guide how to resolve this ?

Software error: The ./data/params.json file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 341. Compilation failed in require at C:\bugzilla\index.cgi line 15. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\bugzilla\index.cgi line 15. For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

[Sun May 21 17:22:58 2023] index.cgi: The ./data/params.json file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 341. [Sun May 21 17:22:58 2023] index.cgi: Compilation failed in require at C:\bugzilla\index.cgi line 15. [Sun May 21 17:22:58 2023] index.cgi: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\bugzilla\index.cgi line 15.

I am expecting that some one will definitely guide me to resolve this issue